# What is the running time of .contains()

Tags: java, time

If set is a HashSet of integers..

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>
```

What is the running time of the method `.contains()`

Example:

```
set.contains(int)
```

I am using Java 7.

Comment: It's all spelled out right there in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `contains` of the HashSet class in Java operates in constant time.  I would also add that other basic operations, such as `add`, `remove`, and `size` also operate in constant time.

Comment: ...with the qualification of "if the hashcode is well-behaved".

Answer (score 1):

To find a value in Hashset always takes const time O(1).

Comment: This is false. It takes O(n) in the worst case.